# How can I download AWS Public Datasets?

Tags: download

https://aws.amazon.com/datasets/ contain many datasets. How can I download an AWS public dataset?

Comment: @[StanislavKralin](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/users/16193/stanislav-kralin): could you please explain your downvote?

Comment: Reason for downvote: Public and Open data are essentially different ... and you did show that in your answer: Public accessible with AWS infrastructure. In order for the data to be open than need to be infrastructure less, get the API or simple download into my machine and start using ... AWS Public datasets are "tied" to their infrastructure (due the size).

Comment: @sb0709 "AWS Public datasets are "tied" to their infrastructure (due the size)" -> What do you mean tied? Some AWS public datasets are small, e.g. https://aws.amazon.com/datasets/freebase-simple-topic-dump/?tag=datasets%23keywords%23encyclopedic is 5 GB.

Comment: @sb0709 "simple download" -> If you know how to use AWS, it takes less than one minute to initiate the download of an AWS Public dataset.

Comment: here is the amazom docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-public-data-sets.html

Comment: @sb0709 What do you want me to see in your link  to AWS documentation?

Comment: the "work around" won't make a Public dataset Open.

Comment: @sb0709 what  "work around" you referring to?

Comment: The doc clearly state the Amazon Pubic Dataset concept, for this I posted.

Comment: @sb0709 I see. I guess you are referring to the first paragraph "Amazon Web Services provides a repository of public data sets that can be seamlessly integrated into AWS cloud-based applications. Amazon stores the data sets at no charge to the community and, as with all AWS services, you pay only for the compute and storage you use for your own applications."? It's compatible with my notion of open data.

Comment: I's so clear from your answer, why you're not acknowledge that you stated clearly is not Open. You use amazon infrastructure.

Comment: @sb0709 What's the issue in using AWS infrastructure?

Comment: is not an issue is that the reason that is not an Open data ... this is the whole point.

Comment: @sb0709 Why it's not open data? I have already addressed your previous arguments.

Comment: Seems the concept of "Public" and "Open" is missed here so won't argue with you related to this: as a difference check the https://project-open-data.cio.gov/policy-memo/ Memorandum for the Heads of Executive Departments and Agencies  section I Definitions: Open data

Comment: @sb0709 From your link "Open data: For the purposes of this Memorandum, the term “open data” refers to publicly available data structured in a way that enables the data to be fully discoverable and usable by end users. " -> AWS Public datasets satisfy those requirements

Comment: is not, data.gov I can use without spinning out the EC2 instances ... for AWS Public Datasets to be Open than need to be reduced in size and made available for download or split in multiple files so can be used by end users.

Comment: @sb0709 spinning out the EC2 instances doesn't go against the definition in your link.

Comment: Just explain me 1 simple thing: why an "t2.small" with 2 gb ram and 1 vCPU is better in accessing the data comparing with my machine that is x100 times powerful than that ?

Comment: @sb0709 I'm not saying it's better. I'm just saying that it  satisfies the open data definition.

Comment: without EC2 environment that data is useless so this is not open ...

Comment: @sb0709 Again, it satisfies the open data definition written in the link you gave me. There is no issue in launching an EC2 instance environment, transferring the data to wherever you wish, then closing the EC2  instance.

Comment: Public dataset from AWS has at least 1 level of access (ec2 instances) that doesn’t make it “Open”. For this simple reason is that data.gov link makes sense because the meaning of the Users access ( you download and use without any enviroment), amazon even state that the collection of their datasets to be used with their products. Also swift introduced same concept with open and public and describes the level of access for each. P.S: is not public dataset the open data.

Comment: @sb0709 AWS datasets can be used in any environment: you just need to download it through an EC2 instance.

Comment: You see that EC2 is the issue here that prevent that collection of datasets to be Open, datasets are open but the level of access make it Public.

Comment: @sb0709 As argued in the above comments, EC2 doesn't prevent that collection of datasets to be Open, according to my definition of open data as well as the link on open data you give me a few comments ago. (https://project-open-data.cio.gov/policy-memo/)

Comment: using your argument/concept, than every private data is an "open data" if we don't consider the level of access (EC2 is a level of access in this case).

Comment: @sb0709  private data means that not everyone can access the data even if they want to. In the case of AWS data sets, anyone can access it because anyone can open a AWS account.

Comment: EC2 does prevent me to access the dataset so for this reason is public and Amazon "labeled" as public and not Open.

Comment: @sb0709 Why does EC2 prevent you from accessing the data set?

Comment: because is a level of access, meaning without it I can't access the data ... that is in contradiction with definition.

Comment: @sb0709 Again why does EC2 prevent you from accessing the data set? Why cannot you create an AWS account?

Comment: is not about creating the account (engineers can do this one very easy and follow your script fo download) but for a non tech user all process is overwhelming, the issue is the type of the data and not the "access" that makes usable the public datasets.

Comment: The same dataset in other place(valid and legal location) without EC2 or any other level of access will be "Open" but here at AWS is only "Public" .

Comment: @sb0709 ok so the issue is account creation?

Comment: Account, instances  ... all this makes the data public. When is "Open" than should be just, for example, only ssh/http download (one click away) not an environment (free or paid is not the case here) to can use it ... here is just only the access and didn't look at the type of the files in S3 ...

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, my downvoting is not related to this Open vs. Public vs. ... discussion. You have answered your question almost instantly, thus, the question was not well-researched. I suppose this site is not a FAQ list or something like. To be honest, I think that the only purpose of many your questions is to attract some traffic and simpathy votes, but probably this is permissible during Beta.

Comment: @StanislavKralin Answering one's own question is not only accepted on Stack Exchange, but encouraged, see [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/178179).

Comment: @sb0709 ok so since  the issue is account creation: This website does already discuss data that require sign ups (e.g., MIMIC dataset: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mimic-iii -> over 100 questions). Plenty of researchers have qualified MIMIC as open data / open access, which means that, according to many researcher, open data may require signing up

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, "this is a thin line" says another answer... OK, I'll post here some translated FAQ lists under the 'russia' tag, and also tons of SPARQL snippets :).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, Account creation only is not the issue here, you create the account to access the data thru EC2, if was only the account creation than not the problem for the data to be "Open", the reason for account is to get EC2 to access the data/modify the format from S3, no EC2 no access to download so this is the "problem" ...

Comment: @sb0709 having to launch an EC2 doesn't go against the definition of open data your link https://project-open-data.cio.gov/policy-memo/ gave

Comment: You pointing to the doc I send and you event didn’t look where is pointed to: “no restrictions should be placed upon their use.” And you clearly state the restrictions(cost related to infrastructure for usage ... so is a limit and as again I stated is a level of access for the public dataset that makes the data “public”, remove the EC2 and problem solved and even amazon will list “Open datasets” instead having current “issue” in labeling/naming their service:))) ) in your answer: Regarding the AWS costs, there 3 types of you should be aware of: Price etc

Comment: @sb0709 using AWS isn't a restriction, and price can be 0.

Comment: This “Can” is a restriction and per definition should not be any tier, so why is so hard to admit what is obviously or you want a proof by contradition here stated ?

Comment: @sb0709 “Can” is not at all a restriction for the datasets for which AWS is free to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take the example of https://aws.amazon.com/datasets/enron-email-data/.

1. Note the snapshot ID of the data set you plan to download. As indicated on https://aws.amazon.com/datasets/enron-email-data/., Enron-email-data's snapshot ID is `snap-d203feb5`.
2. Locate the AWS region in which the snapshot is located. To do, search for the snapshot ID in the list of existing snapshots, e.g. https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Snapshots:visibility=public;search=snap-d203feb5;sort=snapshotId . If you don't find the snapshot, you have to change of AWS region:

   [image]

   In the example of Enron-email-data, it is located in US East (N. Virginia) as well as in US Oregon. (In case you wondered: [How can I know in which US region a snapshot ID is located?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/116302/18147) -> short answer: you have to try all regions yourselves by trying each region in the menu as shown in the screenshot above.)
3. Create an EC2 instance in the same region as the snapshot, i.e. in our example Virginia a.k.a. US-East-1.  To do go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Home and:

   [image]
4. Once the EC2 instance is launched and running, look at its availability zone on https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Instances:sort=instanceId (change the AWS region to the region where you launched the EC2 instance), which in our case `us-east-1c`:

   [image]
5. Go back to https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Snapshots:visibility=public;search=snap-d203feb5;sort=snapshotId and right click on the snapshot and create a volume:

   [image]

   Make sure you select the same availability zone as the one where your EC2 instant is running, which in our case `us-east-1c`:

   [image]
6. In your volume list (e.g. https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Volumes:sort=desc:createTime if you're in US East N. Virginia), right-click on the version you have created, and select "Attach Volume".

   [image]

   It will ask you to which EC2 instance the volume should be attached. Select your EC2 instance.

   [image]
7. SSH into your EC2 instance, and mount the volume as follows:

   ```
   lsblk # <-- it'll give you the name  of the volume, in our case it is xvdf
   sudo mkdir /enron
   sudo mount xvdf /enron
   ```

Done!

---

Below are some tricks to transfer the corpus from the EC2 to your computer.

To transfer the corpus from the EC2 to your computer, assuming that `AWSvirginia.pem` is the private key of the EC2 instance, and that the `184.72.123.192` is the public IP of the EC2 instance:

```
chmod 400 AWSvirginia.pem 
ssh -i AWSvirginia.pem ec2-user@184.72.123.192
rsync -Pav -e "ssh -i AWSvirginia.pem"  ec2-user@184.72.123.192:/enron/ .
```

After the transfer is completed, you can do additional checks as follows (even though `rsync` already checks for file corruption during the transfer):

To get the shasum hash for each file in a directory and its subdirectories (and recursively):

```
find . -type f -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 sha1sum > checksums.txt
```

To check if the files match the shasum hashes:

```
sha1sum -c checksums.txt
```

If there is any issues, it will display at the end of the checksum:

```
sha1sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
```

To check every zip-file in every subfolder:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.zip' -exec unzip -tq {} \;
```

---

Regarding the AWS costs, there 3 types of you should be aware of:

- Price of running an EC2 instance
- Price of transferring data from EC2 instance to outside AWS
- Price of having a volume

Comment: i appreciate all of this, but a) open data doesn't require sign ups and b) has zero implicit associated costs. also, the title is public datasets, but you point to datasets. yes, those are public, but amazon has a different url/data for the public datasets.

Comment: @albert has this been decided somewhere on meta?

Comment: not that i'm aware of. maybe bring it up there?

Comment: @albert well, regarding a) this website does already discuss data that require sign ups (e.g., MIMIC dataset); regarding b) I view AWS as implicit costs (you don't pay for the corpus; you pay for the host infrastructure; and anyway for small corpora, AWS is free).

Comment: points are noted, but don't change the facts around open data. there are ways to access aws datasets and aws public datasets without using their infrastructure and tools. those methods would be appropriate here.

Comment: @albert A user may find a corpus on AWS and may fail to quickly find the same corpus somewhere else. E.g., in my answer I used Enron corpus with attachments, and it's not obvious to find it outside AWS. AWS Public Datasets contain many datasets, and it's useful for open data consumers to know how to access them.

Comment: this is not open data. you can access aws public datsets without signing up/paying. i know this will be useful for many people, actually think this question will get some traffic....still not open data.

Comment: @albert Why this is not  open data? I have already answered your points a and b.

Comment: your answers did not provide solutions that do not require sign ups/costs. brought this up in meta, so lets see what everyone else thinks. i do think this is a great answer and am interested in using it actually. its just not open data. https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/408/aws-datasets-aws-public-datasets